# How to pass variable to react component

Tags: reactjs

For example, we create a react component like this

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="John" />, mountNode);
```

So can i pass the message variable from server? Like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="{{ message }}" />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do should work. You can instantiate a JavaScript variable like you showed, you would just have that `ReactDOM.render` call rendered in your view server-side. No need to render the React component server-side, just have that `render` call rendered on the page.

For example, in your JavaScript file, have the component (`HelloMessage`) just as you showed.

Then, render your second snippet of code (server-side) on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="{{ message }}" />, mountNode);
</script>
```